# Problem verifying source code on Etherscan

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, remix, etherscan

This is really annoying I have tried putting in the ABI. Keep getting a constructor error. I have tried many combinations, nothing seems to work.

Following is the source code I deployed to Testnet [0x34a03193f88ceb2b3ac3ea32b47f7d25544d5f5e](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x34a03193f88ceb2b3ac3ea32b47f7d25544d5f5e#code):

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;
contract mortal {
    /* Define variable owner of the type address*/
    address owner;

    /* this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract */
    function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; }

    /* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
    function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); }
}

contract greeter is mortal {
    /* define variable greeting of the type string */
    string greeting;

    /* this runs when the contract is executed */
    function greeter(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    /* main function */
    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info, eg, contract address, source code, txid, compiler version, deployment environment.

Comment: greeter at 0x34a03193f88ceb2b3ac3ea32b47f7d25544d5f5e (blockchain), Solidity version: 0.4.8+commit.60cc1668.Emscripten.clang, Transaction  0x75bd6721cedfd574ccda2f2d5c5e741900213fc2233f77dff7118ca0eba1b521, not sure deployment environment how would i check that, I am using solidity browser with meta mask to deploy, Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/638969e3ceff12fabc7e7604970cbdad

Comment: This question should be reopened as there is a problem with verifying source code for Solidity versions after 0.4.6 on Etherscan.

Comment: I voted to re-open given the source code is there now and BokkyPooBah is hinting at an answer.

Comment: Can you verify source code that is under 0.4.6?

Comment: Ok so got it to work. Here is what you have to do, take the input code given from etherscan past it into just a text document, than copy the bytecode given from solidity browser, do control find to search for what part of the input code is the actual bytecode. There will be a small amount at the end that is not found, that code is what you need to input into the ABI field on etherscan. Not what you would think, but it works.

Comment: What version did you get it working with? I could only get it working with 0.4.6 and below a few days ago. You may want to self-answer your question to document how you got it working, with screenshots, and taking the last part of the deployment code. I also had to use Browser Solidity instead of Ethereum Wallet as you can control the compiler version in Browser Solidity.

Comment: I am only using 0.4.6. Have not tested others. Yes I had to use the browser too.

Answer (score 1):

Tx [0x75bd...](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x75bd6721cedfd574ccda2f2d5c5e741900213fc2233f77dff7118ca0eba1b521) created the contract at  that you could not get verified as stated in your question above. This was deployed with the source code in your question at compiler version 0.4.8.

Following is your transaction input data:

> 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**0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a68656c6c6f776f726c6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**

And following is your contract bytecode:

> 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

As you stated in your comment, the constructor argument in the source code verificatio screen is the difference between the two bytecodes that is bolded in the first lot of bytecode:

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a68656c6c6f776f726c6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I tried to add the verified source code as shown in the following screens:

[image]

with a continuation of the same screen:

[image]

but it was unsuccessful. Note that optimisation was **Enabled** in the screen above.

I tried verifying the same code, but this time with optimisation **Disabled** and got a successful result:

[image]

So in your case, the problem was cause by deploying code with optimisation **Disabled**.

(I have been having trouble over the last week getting the source code verified and I could only get my source code verified by downgrading to 0.4.6, buy your issue seems to only be the optimisation switch.)