# Is it possible on Ethereum to create a token this way?

Tags: tokens, exchanges, erc-20

Can I make a token using Geth or another Dapp or method and meet these conditions:

- a) I should be able to create the token conveniently without too much programming involved
- b) I should be able to list the token on a decentralized exchange
- c) I should be able to distribute the token to a list of 100 Ethereum addresses at once without paying more than about 0.01 USD in transaction fees

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://tokenfactory.surge.sh/#/

Answer (score 3):

**a) I should be able to create the token conveniently without too much programming involved**

You could try using the source code from the [MiniMe token contract](https://medium.com/giveth/the-minime-token-open-sourced-by-giveth-2710c0210787), my [TestERC20Token](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/blob/master/contracts/TestERC20Token.sol) or one of the main tokens one issue [Supported-ERC20-Tokens](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/Supported-ERC20-Tokens) that is supported by the https://cryptoderivatives.market/ decentralised exchange.

For the easiest deployment, run Ethereum Wallet, select the **Contracts** tab, click on **Deploy New Contract**, paste your source code into the **Solidity Contract Source Code** box, click Deploy and confirm the transaction with your password.

Then ideally, find the newly deployed contract using https://etherscan.io/ and source code verify the deployed bytecode - see 
[Problem verifying source code on Etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12055/problem-verifying-source-code-on-etherscan/12093#12093)
 for the steps to do this.

Here's a simple token with the owner's + 10 addresses pre-allocated:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Basic ERC20 Token Contract. Don't use for any high value contracts without a lot more
// security testing
//
// Enjoy. (c) BokkyPooBah 2017. The MIT Licence.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
contract ERC20Interface {

    // Get the total token supply
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply);

    // Get the account balance of another account with address _owner
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance);

    // Send _value amount of tokens to address _to
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);

    // Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
    // The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to send
    // tokens on your behalf, for example to "deposit" to a contract address and/or to charge
    // fees in sub-currencies; the command should fail unless the _from account has
    // deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism; we propose
    // these standardized APIs for approval:
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);

    // Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
    // If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);

    // Returns the amount which _spender is still allowed to withdraw from _owner
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining);

    // Triggered when tokens are transferred.
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    // Triggered whenever approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) is called.
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}

contract BokkyPooBahTestToken is ERC20Interface {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;

    // Owner of this contract
    address public owner;

    // Balances for each account
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    // Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    // Total supply
    uint256 _totalSupply;

    // Functions with this modifier can only be executed by the owner
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) {
            throw;
        }
        _;
    }

    // Constructor
    function BokkyPooBahTestToken() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        name = "BokkyPooBahTest";
        symbol = "BPBT☺";
        decimals = 18;
        // 1 million with 18 decimal places
        _totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000;
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply * 50 / 100;
        balances[0x00001009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00011009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00021009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00031009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00041009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00051009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00061009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00071009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00081009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
        balances[0x00091009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e] = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply) {
        totalSupply = _totalSupply;
    }

    // What is the balance of a particular account?
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) returns (bool success) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount && _amount > 0) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            balances[_to] += _amount;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
            return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }

    // Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
    // The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to send
    // tokens on your behalf, for example to "deposit" to a contract address and/or to charge
    // fees in sub-currencies; the command should fail unless the _from account has
    // deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism; we propose
    // these standardized APIs for approval:
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount
    ) returns (bool success) {

        if (balances[_from] >= _amount
            && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _amount
            && _amount > 0) {

            balances[_to] += _amount;
            balances[_from] -= _amount;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _amount;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
    // If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _amount;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    // Don't want any ethers leaking into this contract
    function () {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**b) I should be able to list the token on a decentralized exchange**

You can list any ERC20-compliant token on https://cryptoderivatives.market/ . Read the manuals (I'm in the process of writing it up) on how to do this.

**c) I should be able to distribute the token to a list of 100 Ethereum addresses at once without paying more than about 0.01 USD in transaction fees**

When you deploy your token contract, you could set the `totalSupply` to your total supply and assign it to your owner account - for an example see [0x2c875e5ea4706b1978a41b59edf2d3af31d60e70](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2c875e5ea4706b1978a41b59edf2d3af31d60e70#code)

```
// Constructor
function IncentCoffeeToken() {
    _totalSupply = 824;
    owner = msg.sender;
    balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
}
```

It will cost about USD 0.01 to distribute tokens to **each** Ethereum address, for example [Tx 0x404f03c9...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x404f03c9f292101559f8f50f49f8e6014d3ca29798a2e91c64fa37021d5c3325) costs 0.00112580763312 Ether ($0.01).

There are ways to bulk upload the initial token distribution, but it gets complicated. For an example, see @ledgerwatch's The DAO ExtraBalance refund contract - search for **ExtraBalToken Contract** in [How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao) where he added the `fill(...)` and `seal(...)` functions:

```
bool public sealed;
// The 160 LSB is the address of the balance
// The 96 MSB is the balance of that address.
function fill(uint[] data) {
    if ((msg.sender != owner)||(sealed))
        throw;

    for (uint i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        address a = address( data[i] & (D160-1) );
        uint amount = data[i] / D160;
        if (balanceOf[a] == 0) {   // In case it's filled two times, it only increments once
            balanceOf[a] = amount;
            totalSupply += amount;
        }
    }
}

function seal() {
    if ((msg.sender != owner)||(sealed))
        throw;    
    sealed= true;
}
```

The idea here is that you deploy the contract, then call `fill(...)` with an array of `uint256` data where the 160 least-significant-bits is the address of the balance and the 96 most-significant-bits is the balance of that address.